# Let $\epsilon$ be a topos and let $f:Y\to X$ be a morphism. Let $M,N$ be two subobjects of $X$. Is it true that $f^*(M\cap N)=f^*(M)\cap f^*(N)$?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory, pullback

Let $\epsilon$ be a topos and let $f:Y\longrightarrow X$ be a morphism in $\epsilon$. Now, let $M, N$ be two subobjects of $X$. Is it true that $f^*(M\cap N)=f^*(M)\cap f^*(N)$?

For $\epsilon=Set^{C^{{\rm op}}}$ where $C$ is a small category, I know it is true.

I tried to prove it for an arbitrary topos. But I couldn’t prove it and I am not sure that it is true.

Comment: Pullback defines a geometric morphism of topoi, so is left exact. Now use that the intersection is a pullback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true in any category whatsoever (as long as the category has binary pullbacks so the question even makes sense). This is a standard "pullback cube" argument, which is not to say that it's easy! At each of the following steps, you should verify that the diagram remains commutative.

First, form the pullback square defining $M \cap N$:

[image: diagram1]

Next, paste on the pullback squares defining $f^*M$ and $f^* N$:

[image: diagram2]

Next, paste on the pullback square defining $f^*(M \cap N)$:

[image: diagram3]

Because right-hand face is a pullback, the maps $f^*(M \cap N) \to N$ and $f^*(M \cap N) \to Y$ induce a map $f^*(M \cap N) \to f^*N$:

[image: diagram4]

Likewise, because the bottom face is a pullback, the maps $f^*(M \cap N) \to M$ and $f^*(M \cap N) \to Y$ induce a map $f^*(M \cap N) \to f^*(M)$:

[image: diagram5]

Here is our completed "pullback cube":

[image]

Now, using the fact that the back, bottom, right, and "diagonal" (red) squares are pullbacks, prove that the front square is a pullback. This is a direct diagram chase, which @MaliceVidrine did for you :) This setup was important, though, because it tells us that the diagram actually commutes!

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments, pullback has a left adjoint, so it preserves meets in the subobject lattice. But let's do the hairy diagram chasing proof just for fun.

Let $\alpha:f^*M\to M$, $\beta:f^*N\to N$, and $\gamma:f^*(M\cap N)\to M\cap N$ be the "top" edges of the pullbacks; let $m:M\to X$ and $n:N\to X$ be the respective inclusions; and let $i_M$ and $i_N$ be the inclusions of the intersection into $M,N$ respectively.

Now let's say that we have an object $D$ and $a:D\to f^*M$, $b:D\to f^*N$ with $f^*m\circ a=f^*n\circ b$. Then in particular we have $$m\circ\alpha\circ a=f\circ f^*m\circ a =f\circ f^*n\circ b=n\circ\beta\circ b$$ giving a unique morphism $j:D\to M\cap N$ with $i_M\circ j=\alpha\circ a$ and $i_N=\beta\circ b$.

But then $$m\circ i_M\circ j=m\circ\alpha\circ a= f\circ f^*m\circ a$$ giving a unique morphism $k:D\to f^*(M\cap N)$ such that $$f^*m\circ f^*i_M\circ k=f^*m\circ a$$ and $$\gamma\circ k=j.$$

Now notice that $f^*m\circ f^*i_M\circ k=f^*m\circ a$, since $f^*m$ is mono, means that $f^*i_M\circ k=a$. Notice also that our hypotheses on $a,b$ mean $$f^*n\circ f^*i_N\circ k=f^*m\circ f^*i_M\circ k=f^*m\circ a=f^*n\circ b$$
so that $f^*i_N\circ k=b$. Moreover, $k$ is unique with this property: if $f^*i_M\circ k=b=f^*i_M\circ k'$, then $k=k'$ since $f^*i_M$ is mono.

So from our hypotheses on $D,a,b$ there is a unique $k:D\to f^*(M\cap N)$ with $f^*i_M\circ k=a$ and $f^*i_N\circ k=b$; but this says precisely that $f^*(M\cap N)$ is a pullback of $f^*m$ and $f^*n$, making it $f^*M\cap f^*N$.

Answer (score 4):

The standard proof in $Set$ that $f^*(M \cap N) = f^*(M) \cap f^*(N)$ will translate into the internal language of a topos just fine.

The interpretation of this standard proof would go like:

Let $U$ be any test object of the topos and $x : U \to X$ any morphism.  Then
\begin{align*}
x\mathrm{~factors~through~}f^*(M\cap N) & \iff f\circ x\mathrm{~factors~through~}M\cap N \\
& \iff f\circ x\mathrm{~factors~through~}M \wedge f\circ x \mathrm{~factors~through~}N \\
& \iff x\mathrm{~factors~through~}f^*(M) \wedge x\mathrm{~factors~through~}f^*(N) \\
& \iff x\mathrm{~factors~through~}f^*(M) \cap f^*(N).
\end{align*}
Now, applying this with $U := f^*(M \cap N)$ and $x$ the inclusion, we see $f^*(M\cap N)$ factors through $f^*(M) \cap f^*(N)$; and similarly, in the other direction, $f^*(M) \cap f^*(N)$ factors through $f^*(M\cap N)$.  It follows that $f^*(M\cap N) = f^*(M) \cap f^*(N)$ as subobjects of $X$.

(Note that the interpretation of the standard proof that $f^*(M \cup N) = f^*(M) \cup f^*(N)$ would be a little more involved.  Here, we would need to use that $x : U \to X$ factors through $S \cup T$ if and only if there exist $\pi_1 : V_1 \to U$ and $\pi_2 : V_2 \to U$ such that $\pi_1 \sqcup \pi_2 : V_1 \sqcup V_2 \to U$ is an epimorphism; $\pi_1^*(x) = x \circ \pi_1$ factors through $S$; and $\pi_2^*(x) = x \circ \pi_2$ factors through $T$.)

Comment: That's a nice and short proof, could you elaborate a bit more on how this relates to the proof in the accepted answer? As far as I know, we have to prove that $f^\ast(M \cap N)$ is the pullback of $f^\ast(M) \to Y$ and $f^\ast(N) \to Y$. How does this method proves that exactly?

Comment: I'd imagine that this could be transformed into the proof in the accepted answer, with the main difference maybe being that this proof uses the fact that monomorphisms are involved to conclude that a lot of the diagrams are pretty much automatically commutative.  Haven't thought about it in that much detail, though.  And maybe the proofs of the facts that $x$ factors through $f^*(S)$ if and only if $f \circ x$ factors through $S$, and that $x$ factors through $S \cap T$ if and only if $x$ factors through $S$ and factors through $T$, could serve as abstractions of parts of the other proof.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Yes, the main reason why I was wondering about this proof, is that I'm seemingly missing some distinction of proofs in the internal language of a topos, and general mathematical proofs. It seems there is a subtle interplay that I can't get my hands on.  The accepted proof is the method I would go about to prove something like this, but the method of your proof seems less cumbersome.

Comment: Well, I think of the "interpretation of the internal language of a topos" strategy as being very much an extension of the Yoneda lemma strategy that can work so effectively in general category theory, for example to construct an isomorphism $X \simeq Y$ by constructing an isomorphism of functors $\operatorname{Hom}(-, X) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(-, Y)$ (often as a chain of building block isomorphisms such as $Hom(-, X \times Y) \simeq Hom(-, X) \times Hom(-, Y)$).

Comment: And yes, there is a distinction to be drawn between formal proofs in the internal language of a topos, and interpretations of those proofs.  The former looks like just an intuitionistic type theory with the addition of subset types, so you can pretty much work as if you were in constructive $Set$.  The "interpretation" takes any formal proof which works in the internal language, and turns it into a theorem which works in any topos.